# Value object design pattern in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, design-patterns

I am just looking design patterns used in Flex. Please tell me about value object design pattern and how is it implemented in Flex. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Value Object is really nothing more than a data object.  It is OK to have some methods on a Value Object, in my opinion... but they exist for convenience and don't really add any behavior.  For instance, here is an example of a VO:

```
[Bindable]
public class PersonVO {
    public var firstName:String;
    public var lastName:String;

    public function PersonVO(firstName:String, lastName:String) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public function clone():PersonVO {
        return new PersonVO(firstName, lastName);
    }
}
```

Note that this class is mutable by default which is why I added the `[Bindable`] tag.  You are likely to want to use data binding with this class and you need `[Bindable]` (or some equivalent) to make that happen.

I actually prefer immutable value objects in many cases.  Here is how you would implement a mutable VO:

```
public class PersonVO {
    private var _firstName:String;
    private var _lastName:String;

    public function PersonVO(firstName:String, lastName:String) {
        _firstName = firstName;
        _lastName = lastName;
    }

    public function get firstName():String { return _firstName; }
    public function get lastName():String { return _lastName; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Brian Genisio. Now, I've got a clear picture of VO :)

Answer (score 2):

A [VO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) is similar to a bean if you are from a Java background. I would code a VO as

```
public class UserVO
{
     private var _name:String;

     public function set name(value:String):void
     {
          _name = value;
     }

     public function get name():String
     {
           return _name;
      }
}
```

Here we declare private variables and provide setter and getter methods to set the value for the members variables. Although it is not advised, you can perform range checking before assigning values inside the setter method. You can access the members as :

```
var userVo:UserVO = new UserVO();
userVo.name = "some name";
```

Comment: Check out this wikipedia link : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object

Comment: Thank you very much @silverback for this much clear explanation but in Flex, VO dont have methods but I came to know the concept in Java. Thank you again :)

Comment: These are not your normal methods, they are called mutators. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method

Comment: Hey @silverback,thanks again. I don't know much about these Mutator methods. Now I came to know :)

Comment: Why are you using mutators here?  With the code you have shown, there is no benefit to writing it that way over public properties: `public var name:String`.  In fact, writing it this way makes it more difficult to make "notifiable" with the `[Bindable]` tag.

Comment: @Kishor Kumar: Value Objects can have methods.  Just don't add behavior to them.  Make them convenience methods... like `clone()`

Comment: i agree with @Brian. What i have given is a simple explanation. You can make the class Bindable to make it bindable. I had used a derived property for a UserVo once called `fullName` that would simply `return firstname + lastname`, but you cannot set a value for that. The Mutator method would append the first name and last name and return it. I am not sure if that is a good practice, i was able to simplify the usage of this functionality in some parts of my UI.

Comment: **TIP** In Flash Builder 4.5, pressing **Ctrl+F1** will automatically generate BINDABLE getters/setters!!! Mutators are really useful when adding properties to a flex component (so you can invalidate, mark dirty, etc.) but in a simple VO I'd have to agree with just using public properties.

Comment: Thank you all of you. Really, you gave me so much information on Value Object which I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

The following site is worth to have a look: http://www.flashmonkey.co.uk/using-value-objects-in-flash/